# Error running Turtlesim noetic

Tags: turtlesim, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good Afternoon All,

I am going through the tutorial at : **http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes.**  I ran the command :
**rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node**  and it generated the error :

*/opt/ros/noetic/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

I verified that  libQt5Core.so.5 is installed, and idea on how to resolve?  Please advise?

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354808/error-running-turtlesim-noetic/) by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2020-06-12**:
This doesn't seem to be an issue with ROS, but rather with your system. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034313/ubuntu-18-4-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dir) for example. If that doesn't help, can you provide system details?

**Comment by [chethw](https://answers.ros.org/users/76184/chethw/) on 2021-06-16**:
Im trying to install ros/gazebo using WSL in ubuntu 20.4 and getting the same error. any clue to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have solved the same problem.

Maybe this problem is due to the version of WSL in ubuntu 20.04.

To solve this problem, refer to this URL:
[link text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034313/ubuntu-18-4-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dir)

```
whereis libQt5Core.so.5
# copy that address
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

Good Luck.

---

Originally posted by [KindlyAccept](https://answers.ros.org/users/80864/kindlyaccept/) with karma: 26 on 2021-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2022-03-25**:
This worked thanks